# SQL Table-Valued User-Defined Functions between TWo dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to build a table valued user defined function using two parameters
input like `select * from func_1('01/01/2012','09/09/2015');`

output should be like :

```
month quator semi_annual annual 
 1     1      1            2012
 2     1      1            2012
 3     1      1            2012
 4     2      1            2012
 5     2      1            2012
 6     2      1            2012
 7     3      2            2012
 .     .       .            ...
 .     .      .             ....

      upto 
9       3    2             2015
```

I need a table valued function for this.

i tried a code like this

```
create function func3_D_D
(@startDate date, @endDate date)
RETURNS @dates table
(months int,quatorly int,Semi_anuual int,Annual int)
As
Begin 
declare
@months int,
@quatorly int,
@Semi_anuual int,
@Annual int;




select @months= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @startDate, @endDate);
select @quatorly= DATEDIFF(QUARTER, @startDate, @endDate);
select @Semi_anuual= DATEDIFF(QUARTER, @startDate, @endDate)/ 2;
select @Annual= DATEDIFF(YEAR, @startDate, @endDate);

WHILE (@endDate > @startDate) 

begin
insert into @dates
select @months,@quatorly,@Semi_anuual,@Annual;
End;
return;
End;
```

Comment: and what exactly have you tried? SO is not a code generation factory.

Comment: This seems more like you're setting us a task rather than asking a question. What help do you need with it? By help I mean how can we help with the code you've currently tried and that you're going to update your question with?

Comment: i mentioned the code which i tried ,bit in that am only able to see the count difference for month,quator ,semi annual and annual, but i need to presenta table like i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop for this is about a awful for performance as you can get. You need to use a tally table for this type of thing. You need to start thinking in sets instead of row by row. Once you have a tally table (which I generated here with a cte), this is pretty simple.

```
create function MyFunctionThatGetsDatesByRange
(
    @StartDate DATE
    , @EndDate DATE
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
    WITH
        E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
        E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
        E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
        cteTally(N) AS 
        (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
        )

    select DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartDate) as date
        , DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartDate)) as Month
        , DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartDate)) as Quarter
        , CASE when DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartDate)) <= 2 then 1 else 2 end as SemiAnnual
        , DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @StartDate)) as Annual
    from cteTally
    where N <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate);

GO

declare @StartDate date = '2012-01-01'
    , @EndDate date = '2015-09-09';

select *
from dbo.MyFunctionThatGetsDatesByRange(@StartDate, @EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

hi thanks for your reply i achived that by using the below code.

```
create function func5_D_D
(@startDate date, @endDate date)
RETURNS @dates table
(months int,
quators int,
semi_annual int,
annual int)
As
Begin 

WHILE @startDate <= @endDate
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO @dates(months,quators,semi_annual,annual) values (MONTH(@startDate), datepart(qq,@startDate),
 case when datepart(qq,@startDate) in (1,2) then 1 else
 2 End,datepart(yyyy,@startdate))

 SET @startDate = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@startDate)

 END
return;
end;
```

Comment: No offense but that is just the wrong way to do this. I provided you a super fast set based approach and you went right back to using a loop. You have two of the slowest constructs in t-sql in a single piece of code. First is loops, they are just inefficient. Then you have a multi statement table valued function. These are even slower than a scalar function.

Comment: Hi  @SeanLange,  

Thanks for your response am a SQL beginner,thanks for your explanation and am not able to understand your coding ,will you please explain little bit whta you did in the below coding and about tlaly table  

WITH
        E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
        E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
        E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
        cteTally(N) AS 
        (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
        )        -- Thanks in Advance .

Comment: I am using a tally table. Please this article for a complete explanation. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 0):

Difference between two dates in X years Y Months and Z days (For example: Age in Years, Months and days)
We can use a script like below to get the difference between two dates in Years, Months and days.

Difference between two dates in X years Y Months and Z days (For example: Age in Years, Months and days)
We can use a script like below to get the difference between two

```
datDECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '2010-01-01 23:59:59.000', 
        @ToDate   DATETIME = '2015-01-02 00:00:00.000',
        @Years INT, @Months INT, @Days INT, @tmpFromDate DATETIME
SET @Years = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate)
 - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate),
          @FromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 


SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(YEAR, @Years , @FromDate)
SET @Months =  DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)
 - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate),
          @tmpFromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(MONTH, @Months , @tmpFromDate)
SET @Days =  DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)
 - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate),
          @tmpFromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

SELECT @FromDate FromDate, @ToDate ToDate, 
       @Years Years,  @Months Months, @Days Days
s in Years, Months and days.
```